# Найдите ошибку в коде питон

Tags: python

Само задание звучит так: описать функцию Calc(A, B, Op) вещественного типа, выполняющую над ненулевыми вещественными числами A и B одну из арифметических операций и возвращающую ее результат. Вид операции определяется целым параметром Op: 1 — вычитание, 2 — умножение, 3 — деление, остальные значения — сложение. С помощью Calc выполнить для данных A и B операции, определяемые данными целыми N1, N2, N3. Помогите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Если можете поправьте код или если можно в одну строку. Заранее спасибо.

```py
def proc22(a, b, op):
    if op == 1:
        return a - b
    if op == 2:
        return a * b
    if op== 3:
        return a / b
    return a + b
```

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что что-то делаете не так?

Comment: Код корректный (ну, разве что функция не так называется, как в условии сказано). В одну строку пытаться все впихнуть - так себе идея.

Answer (score 1):

```
def proc22(a, b, op):
   if op == 1:
      return a - b
   elif op == 2:
      return a * b
   elif op== 3:
      return a / b
   else:
      return a + b
```

Comment: упадет функция при вызове `proc22(1,1)`

Comment: @Dmitry В условии не сказано же, что параметр не обязательный

Comment: @CrazyElf а, да, пролюбил(

Answer (score 0):

Вариант когда `op` может не передаваться

```py
def proc22(a, b, op=None): # здесь
   if op == 1:
      return a - b
   elif op == 2:
      return a * b
   elif op== 3:
      return a / b
   return a + b
```

протестируем

```
print(proc22(2,3))
print(proc22(2,3,0))
print(proc22(2,3,1))
print(proc22(2,3,2))
print(proc22(2,3,3))

# OUT
# 5
# 5
# -1
# 6
# 0.666666666666666
```

Comment: *остальные значения — сложение.* - вроде как не тоже самое, что необязательный параметр?

Comment: @splash58 да, перечитал уже. Но как вариант оставлю. Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

В одну строку можно например так чисто по приколу. Но вряд ли вы такое проходили:

```
def proc22(a, b, op):
    return {1: a.__sub__, 2: a.__mul__, 3: a.__truediv__}.get(op, a.__add__)(b)
```